# Duplicate Arrays Output

Tags: c#, arrays, output

i'm currently learning arrays in C#, and as part of my teaching I have the following code:

```
            oldest = Data.ages[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < Data.count; i++)
            {
                if (Data.ages[i] > oldest)
                    oldest = Data.ages[i];



            }
            textOldest.Text = "Oldest: " + oldest;
```

Now this is a small part of the code, there's basically 5 ages put into a textbox in windows phone emulator and this is supposed to find the highest and display it in a textblock, however if you put the same age in as the highest ages i.e if the 5 inputs were 10,10,11,11,11 I'm not getting an error message and I don't understand why, since when 11 is compared with 11 it is not more than and should not work (I think).

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you get an error? You are comparing to see if 11 is larger than 11, wich it is not, and so the value of 'oldest' simply does not change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking about it completely the wrong way. You're absolutely right, oldest ends up at 11, and then when compared to the 11 and it does not change so stays at 11.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see an error, the program is executing perfectly fine.

```
//Checking if Greater than. 11 > 5 is TRUE but 11 > 11 is NOT
if (Data.ages[i] > oldest) 
   //It is greater than
else
   //Its Not greater than
```

If you wanted to, you could check if its `>=` Greater than or Equal to.